# JPA insertable and updatable with View and SecondaryTable

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Thera are oracle view  ***vendor_view*** and table ***vendors*** (vendors table contains only PK with name id  for simplicity)

```
create view vendor_view as
    select id as vid, 'YES' as active
    from vendors;
```

Coresponding entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "vendors")
@SecondaryTable(name = "vendor_view", pkJoinColumns = {@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "vid", referencedColumnName = "id")})
public class Vendor {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    @Column(table = "vendor_view", name = "vid", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Long vid;

    @Column(table = "vendor_view", name = "active", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private String active;


     getter and setter....
}
```

When i try to persist new Vendor entity then face with issue:

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not prepare statement; SQL [insert into vendor_view (vid) values (?)]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement
            at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:238)
.....
Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE or TRUNCATE not permitted for table or view
            at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
```

JPA Implementation is Hibirnate.
Question is why Hibirnate generate ***insert*** query for field that mark as ***insertable = false, updatable = false*** ?

Comment: See my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/37160701/1356423. Unless you are explicitly setting one of the fields mapped to the `@SecondaryTable` (which you shouldn't be if it is a view) then no insert update statement is executed. If you are then an insert statement will be made for ID column even if all other fields are mapped an non-insertable/updateable.

Answer (score 0):

As hibernate doesn't know whether the table you are trying to insert is a table or a view until and unless it interacts with the database. So it is runtime exception which can be checked only when Java program interacts with Database.

It is similar to even if table doesn't exist it will make query but on runtime it will throw exception.

Answer (score 0):

You would do that when the responsibility of `creating/udpating` the related entity in question isn't in the current entity. E.g. you have a `Person` and an `Address`. You'd like to add `insertable=false`, `updatable=false` to the `@OneToMany relationship` with the `Person` entity in the `Address` entity, simply because it's not the responsibility of the Address entity to create or update a Person. It's the other way round. This is not really a technical, but more a semantic/natural decision.

Comment: Yea i knowe it, but it do not connected to my question.Because i have marked corresponding field with  insertable = false, updatable = false