# JPA secondary table as read only view - hibernate still tries to insert rows

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, view

I've got the following entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ONE")
@SecondaryTable(name = "VIEW_TWO", pkJoinColumns = @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="ONE_ID"))
public class CpBracket {

@Id
private Long id;

@Column(name="progress", table="VIEW_TWO", updatable = false, insertable = false)
private int progress = 0;

(...)
}
```

As you see, this entity uses table **ONE** and (read only) view **VIEW_TWO**. When I'm persisting the entity, hibernate is performing insert into view:

```
insert into VIEW_TWO (ONE_ID) values (?)
```

It is ignoring the non-updatable and non-insertable column **progress** (that's good) and it is still trying to insert value of **ONE_ID** column. As far as I know, the annotation @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn marks selected column as **insertable=false** and **updatable=false**.

How can I prevent hibernate from inserting rows into secondary table (view)?

Comment: There's a duplicate here with no accepted answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34208122/jpa-insertable-and-updatable-with-view-and-secondarytable

Comment: As an alternative you could map as a `@OneToOne` relationship with no cascade rather than as a `@SecondaryTable`. I think this would fix the issue.

Comment: if you're persisting an object, where do you expect that objects entry in the SecondaryTable to come from if you want to prevent it inserting ?

Comment: @AlanHay, It is no possible to map integer using one to one relationship.

Comment: @NeilStockton , you're not serious, right? If you are, here is my explanation: **VIEW_TWO** is a view which performs quite complex aggregating operation which also joins table **ONE** - hence it will **always** contain one row for **every** row in the table **ONE**

Comment: View Two becomes an Entity and you map a one to one to that Entity.

Comment: @AlanHay that's overcomplicated. VIEW_TWO has only two columns: **ONE_ID** and **PROGRESS**. I want to map single column to a field in my entity.

Comment: Maybe, but it will work: unlike your current solution. Sorry I tried to help.

Comment: @AlanHay I appreciate that. Thanks for your input. :)

Comment: Other solution is to use Hibernate specific non-JPA `@Formula` column. `@SecondaryTable` is not going to work.

Comment: @carbolymer Bit late but see my update which explains how to fix the issue using `@SecondaryTable` rather than `@OneToOne`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> As far as I know, the annotation `@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn` marks selected
>   column as insertable=false and updatable=false.

I do not believe this can be the case: how then do we get records inserted into the `@SecondaryTable` when it is an actual table rather than a view?

As neither `@SecondaryTable` or `@PrimarykeyJoinColumn` have a means to prevent insert then it would appear that your original solution is not going to work and an alternative is required.

One option is to map VIEW_TWO as an `@Entity` and link to your class `CPBracket` as a `@OneToOne` relationship with cascade options set to none.

```
@Entity
@Table(name ="VIEW_TWO")
private CpBracketSummaryData(){

}


@Entity
@Table(name = "ONE")
public class CpBracket {

    @OneToOne
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
    private CPBracketSummaryData summaryData;

    public int getSomeValue(){
        return summaryData.getSomeValue();
    }
}
```

The second option would be to use the non JPA compliant, Hibernate specific `@Formula` annotation.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ONE")
public class CpBracket {

       @Formula("native sql query")
       private int someValue;
}
```

### Update October 2016

I have revisited this in both Hibernate 4.3.10.Final and 5.1.0.Final and it is possible to have the view as a `@SecondaryTable` without the insert: *if you have the correct mappings*.

**Scenario 1**

Load an entity for edit and do not touch any fields mapped to the secondary table. No update is issued to the secondary table

**Scenario 2**

Create and save a new entity and do not set any fields mapped to the secondary table. No insert is issued for the secondary table

**Scenario 3**

Create or update an entity including a field mapped to a secondary table and where this field is marked as insertable = false and updateable = false. An insert **is** made to the secondary table only for the ID field -the  behaviour reported in the original question.

The issue with the mapping in the original question is the fact that the secondary table field is a primitive type and therefore when saving a new entity Hibernate does think a record has to be written to the secondary table with a value of zero.

```
@Column(name="progress", table="VIEW_TWO", updatable = false, insertable = false)
private int progress = 0;
```

The solution then is to replace primitives with the corresponding wrapper types and leave  them as null. Then when saving a new record there is nothing to write to the secondary table and no insert will be made:

```
@Column(name="progress", table="VIEW_TWO")
private Integer progress;
```

Comment: Wow, thanks for looking into this case still after half of year. I have managed to move logic from the view to the java code and avoid using `@SecondaryTable`

Answer (score 0):

I solved a similar problem with @SecondaryTable, which was a database view. So maybe it will help someone else.

The problem was on cascade delete to @SecondaryTable, when record from primary table was deleted.

As a solution, I implemented RULE on view for delete

```
CREATE RULE on_delete AS ON DELETE TO my_view DO INSTEAD(
    select 1;
)
```

Similar solution can be used for INSERT and UPDATE operation on view.