# JPA: persist object with an AS query

Tags: java, jpa

I have a DB table with N fields.

And I have a Java `@Entity` object with these N fields, too.

I want to do a find query, and on this query I want to return an extra fields with the "AS" option. For example "AS myDate".

Imagine my object is Test. When I return the values of the find query, I do:

```
return (Test)qry.getSingleResult();
```

And this result set the `myDate` result on the variable of the object.

But when I do an insert with EntityManager persist method, it gives me an error because `myDate` is not a field of my table.

If I put `@Transient` over this field, the insert works, but the `getSingleResult` does not give me this field because of the `@Transient`.

I don't know how can I do it.

Also... How can I specify on my Entity class a field that does not exists on my table, but exists with an "AS" when I do a select on this table?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: post the query and the entity itself

Comment: See the suggestions here to similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41984002/spring-jpa-repository-sub-query-in-native-query/41988142#41988142

Comment: Well, finally, I use @NamedNativeQuery with the AS on the query, and on the java class, I obtain the results field to field, without matching an object, with this code: `List<Object[]> resultList = qry.getResultList();
   if (resultList!=null && resultList.size()>0) {
    Object[] result = resultList.get(0);
    if (result!=null) {
     myObject.setId(((BigDecimal)result[0]).longValue()); (...)`