# Linking two object by code (not ID) using Eclipselink JPA

Tags: jpa, eclipselink

i have two tables:

```
area (
  id int PK autoincrement
  code varchar
)

products (
  id int PK autoincrement
  area_id int
)
```

And the objets are defined like this:

```
class Product {
    ...
    @JoinColumn(name = "area_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    @ManyToOne
    @Expose
    private Area area;
    ...    
}
```

This works fine but I want that area to be a String with the code used in the table **area** column **code**.

```
class Product {
    ...
    ???
    private String area;
    ...    
}
```

What should be the annotations to make this work?

Thanks!

Comment: why not keep the mapping and use area.code whenever you need the code?

Comment: I'm implementing the json rest API, and I want to make it as simple as possible. I want the user to send only the code without the need to know what area.id is

Comment: Don't mix your entity and webservices classes and you wont have problem like this. Your EJB classes should only model your database and you need to create another set of classes just for webservices and map data in between them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is some poor soul with the same problem, here is how I did it:

Using transformers. So the field area is defined like this:

```
@Transformation(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, optional = false)
@ReadTransformer(transformerClass = AreaAttributeTransformer.class)
@WriteTransformers({
        @WriteTransformer(
                transformerClass = AreaFieldTransformer.class,
                column = @Column(name = "area_id", nullable = false))
})
@Expose
private String area;
```

Then those clases work like this:

**AreaAttributeTransformer**

```
public class AreaAttributeTransformer implements AttributeTransformer {

private AbstractTransformationMapping mapping;

@Override
public void initialize(AbstractTransformationMapping abstractTransformationMapping) {
    this.mapping = abstractTransformationMapping;
}


@Override
public Object buildAttributeValue(Record record, Object o, Session session) {
    for (DatabaseField field : mapping.getFields()) {
        if (field.getName().contains("area_id")) {

            EntityManager em = MyEntityManagerFactory.getENTITY_MANAGER_FACTORY().createEntityManager();
            List results = em.createNamedQuery("Areas.findById")
                    .setParameter("id", record.get(field))
                    .getResultList();
            if (results.size() > 0)
                return ((Area) results.get(0)).getCode();
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

}

**AreaFieldTransformer**

```
public class AreaFieldTransformer implements  FieldTransformer {

private AbstractTransformationMapping mapping;

@Override
public void initialize(AbstractTransformationMapping abstractTransformationMapping) {
    this.mapping = abstractTransformationMapping;
}

@Override
public Object buildFieldValue(Object o, String s, Session session) {
    if (o instanceof RouSub) {
        EntityManager em = MyEntityManagerFactory.getENTITY_MANAGER_FACTORY().createEntityManager();
        List results = em.createNamedQuery("Area.findByCode")
                .setParameter("area", ((Area) o).getCode())
                .getResultList();
        if (results.size() > 0)
            return ((Area)results.get(0)).getId();
    }
    return null;
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

Try to use a combination of [@SecondaryTable](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/SecondaryTable.html) and [@Column](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/Column.html) annotations. Something like this:

```
@Entity    
@SecondaryTable(name="area", pkJoinColumns=@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="id", referencedColumnName="area_id"))
class Product {
    ...
    @Column(name="code", table = "area")
    private String code;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Hi! thanks for the reply. This works fine for GET methods but what about PUT?

Exception Description: Missing mapping for field [area.id].
Descriptor: RelationalDescriptor( xxx.Product --> [DatabaseTable(products), DatabaseTable(area)])

Comment: @MarianoL Did you try to save a new Product with an area code which already exists or no? Also, please have a look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37157291/jpa-secondary-table-as-read-only-view-hibernate-still-tries-to-insert-rows